# Wildcard for generated Content files in vcxproj

Tags: msbuild, vcxproj, windows-application-packaging

I have a C++ desktop app that uses several folders of resources, some of which are generated at buildtime like this:

```
 <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
      <Command>generate stuff</Command>
    </PreBuildEvent>
    <PostBuildEvent>
      <Command>xcopy stuff to $(OutDir)
               xcopy otherstuff to $(OutDir)</Command>
    </PostBuildEvent>
 </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

('otherstuff' represents pre-existing, not generated resources. I have good reasons why I cannot enumerate the contents of those folders file by file inside the vcxproj.)

However, when packaging the application for the Windows Store via a Windows Application Packaging Project (.wapproj), the generated stuff is not included in the .msix, because the wapproj, understandably, only knows about those resources that are referenced with a `<Content Include="" />`.

Since the resources are generated at buildtime, they don't exist when the .vcxproj is evaluated, so adding this to the vcxproj doesn't work:

```
<Content Include="stuff\**" 
         Link="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" 
         CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
<Content Include="otherstuff\**" 
         Link="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" 
         CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-files-and-wildcards?view=msvc-160), wildcards are not supported in .vcxproj anyway, however with VS 16.11.24 / MSBuild 16.11.2, they seem to work for 'otherstuff', that is as long as the files are already present at evaluation time. Using a suggestion from the same docs, I tried to move the wildcards to a Target:

```
<Target Name="CopyStuff" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="stuff\**" 
               Link="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" 
               CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
      <Content Include="otherstuff\**" 
               Link="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"             
               CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This results in the weirdest behaviour ever, since the files from the two wildcards start overwriting one another, as if MSBuild accidentally performed a cross product of the two sets of files. Example from the buildlog:

```
Copying file from "otherstuff\vk_swiftshader_icd.json" to "stuff\assets\help_active.svg".
```

Here are some alternative approaches I've tried, none of which were successful:

```
<Target>
    <CreateItem ...>
```

```
 <Target>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ContentFilesProjectOutputGroupOutput Include="stuff/**" />
    </ItemGroup>
 </Target>
```

I'm also looking at the last part of [the vcxproj of WindowsTerminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/814e44bf45762ee878b41553c7048c6ffbf1e63e/src/cascadia/WindowsTerminal/WindowsTerminal.vcxproj) because they seem to somehow override the task that wapproj uses to query the original project for packaging outputs, but I haven't made sense of that yet or whether it would work with buildtime generated files.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the magic incantation I needed:

```
<Target Name="CopyStuff" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <ItemGroup>       
      <Stuff Include="stuff\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <CreateItem Include="@(Stuff)"
                AdditionalMetadata="CopyToOutputDirectory=PreserveNewest;TargetPath=%(Stuff.RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Content" />
    </CreateItem>
  </Target>
```